# Cumulus - Open Source RTMFP Server

Tags: rtmfp, cumulus

> https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus

Has anyone worked with this outside of the lan?

From what I have read on here and other sources, its useless unless the firewall is correctly configured : [RTMFP and firewalls/routers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332762/rtmfp-and-firewalls-routers)

If you have worked with this, can you please give your impressions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of this server should be to allow it to get through firewalls with ease. Having said that, I see a number of bug reports on the project, so it is possible that this is just not correctly working in Cumulus yet.